# What is the best practice for on-the-fly Field Configuration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, configuration, jira

I'm going to implement an **Asp.net MVC 4.0** application in which use can change the **field positions** on it. In Administration panel there is a page which user can select the **field poisition on the screen**. User also can **change some of the fields properties**. (Something like **Atlassian Jira** [Field Configuration](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Specifying+Field+Behaviour) and **[Screen Configuration](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Defining+a+Screen)**)

I don't know how should I creat final pages. Actually I'm looking for a **best practice** which let me read the content of a page from a service and based on that reorder the page elements.

Any help is appriciated.